# Magento - get product name inside reviews list.phtml and summary.phtml

Tags: php, magento

In order to get the google rich snippets I have to provide the product name for each review and for the review summary.
I load the review/product/view/list.phtm and the review/helper/summary.phtml in the product view.phtml template.
I'm trying to print the product name in these templates,but every attempted I made broke the page... Here what I've tried:

```
<meta itemprop="itemreviewed" content = "<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')?>">
<meta itemprop="itemreviewed" content = "<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getId())->getName() ?>">
<meta itemprop="itemreviewed" content = "<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductInfo()->getName()) ?>">
<meta itemprop="itemreviewed" content = "<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_review->getProductName()) ?>">
<meta itemprop="itemreviewed" content = "<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>">
```

None of these worked... or I got nothing or I got error like "Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in ..."

Could anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!
Daniele

Comment: How are you retrieving $_product?

Comment: I'm really a beginner... so I don't know what I've done... I tried to use the code that work in other template. So (if I've understood) the problem is that in review/product/view/list.phtm and in review/helper/summary.phtml $_product is not defined...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getName(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>`

That should be efficient for what you need. 
For future reference you can navigate to `app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[theme]/template/catalog/view.phtml` to find that above code line.